# data.table fread() sometimes crashes the R session

Tags: r, data.table, fread

data.table fread() sometimes crashes my R session when reading tab-separated or csv files. This happens deterministically depending on the input file.

```
> fread('C:/TEMP/single_cell_ia.txt', verbose = TRUE)
Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
File opened, filesize is 0.000099 GB.
Memory mapping ... ok
Detected eol as \n only (no \r afterwards), the UNIX and Mac standard.
Positioned on line 1 after skip or autostart
This line is the autostart and not blank so searching up for the last non-blank ... line 1
Detecting sep ...
```

[R session crashes here]

Files that give problems with fread() can be read with read.delim() or read.csv() without problems. I have performed a number of tests with a tab-separate file and observed the following:

problem solved:

- open in Excel (make no changes) and save again as tab-separated text file
- replace text in the header by other text of different length using sed command under Unix
- replace text in the header by other text of different length using the Search --> Find --> Replace menu in Notepad++ under Windows

problem not solved:

- make a copy of the file
- open in Notepad++ (make no changes) and "save as..."
- replace text  in the header by other text of the same length using sed command under Unix
- replace text in the header by other text of the same length using the Search --> Find --> Replace menu in Notepad++ under Windows

I couldn't create a small artificial example where the problem occurs to post it here but I'm happy to send over the file I used for testing (104 kB; 14 rows; 803 columns)

Thanks,
Steffen.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.10.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.3
```

Comment: Yes please upload the file somewhere, or email it to me.

Comment: Can you create a [public gist](https://gist.github.com/) with the copy-pasted contents of the file?

Comment: I uploaded the file here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f3cbda02aee96670f4ec722e9c89c8dc#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: hi guys. just wondering if there are any updates on this? thanks!